# jQuery and Ajax: include javascript in the <head> element, instead of associating with the HTML file

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use jQuery Ajax to update div's. One thing bothered me: for the inserted HTML data, it seems that I have to put its associating javascripts in the file, instead of including them in the `<head>` element. Otherwise, the Ajax won't work. For example, I have the following HTML and jQuery codes:

`base.html`:

```
...
<head>
...
<script>   <!-- Get script -->
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.getContent').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(url);
      return false;
  });
});
</script>
</head>
...
<div id="content">
  ...
  <!-- Insert the 'addMember.html' into 'content' div -->
  <a class="getContent" href="/addMember">Add member</a>
  ...
</div>
...
```

`addMember.html`:

```
...
<form class="postContent" action="/addMember" method="post">
  ...
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script>   <!-- Post script -->
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.postContent').ajaxForm({
    success: function(returnData) {
      $('#container2').html(returnData);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

If I click `Add member`, the `addMember.html` will be loaded into the `content` div. And then when I click `Submit`, the result of the post will also update the `content` div. Everything works fine. However, I would like to put the 'Post script' in the `<head>` element too, so that other pages can share the code. But, the Ajax won't work if I do so (i.e., the post result wouldn't update `content` div). How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Just make it into a function and call the function when the new content loads.

```
function postScript() {
  $('.postContent').ajaxForm({
    success: function(returnData) {
      $('#container2').html(returnData);
    }
  });
}
...
$('#content').load(url, postScript);
```

Comment: So I need to put function `postScript` in the `base.html` file, and put `$('#content').load(...);` in `$(document).ready...` of the `addMember.html` file. Is that right? What will `url` be then? Thanks.

Comment: @Yuan-LiangTang `postScript` goes in the `base.html` and `$('#content').load(...);` stays where it is in `base.html`

Comment: Thanks Musa. I don't quite understand. The function `postScript()` statys in `base.html`. This is OK. But `$('#content').load(...)` is also in `base.html`? Shouldn't it be in `addMember.html`?

Comment: @Yuan-LiangTang you are replacing `$('#content').load(url);` in `base.html` with `$('#content').load(url, postScript);`

Comment: Got it. What if I have many jQuery functions in `base.html` to be shared by many other pages? For example, functions like `getContent`, `postContent`, `getContent2`, `postContent2`, ..., which means I can have such statements as `<a id="getContent" ...>`, `<form id="postContent2" action="..." method="post">`, etc., in other pages.